# FindNoCase, Find is not working coldfusion 9

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfml

Both FindNoCase and Find funcions are returning 0 values for all cases. I'm working on Coldfusion 9.

```
<cfoutput>#Find("aaInternationalbb", "International")#</cfoutput>       ->o/p:0
<cfoutput>#Find("aalbb", "International")#</cfoutput>                   ->o/p:0
<cfoutput>#FindNoCase("aaInternationalbb", "International")#</cfoutput> ->o/p:0
<cfoutput>#FindNoCase("aalbb", "International")#</cfoutput>             ->o/p:0
```

Please let me know how to make this work. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not working because you have given the parameters in wrong order. The syntax for each of [`find()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7e7c.html) and [`findNoCase()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6e16.html) are

```
 FindNoCase(substring, string [, start ])

 Find(substring, string [, start ])
```

So you have to try like:

```
  <cfoutput>#Find( "International","aaInternationalbb")#</cfoutput>       
  <cfoutput>#Find( "International","aalbb")#</cfoutput>                   
  <cfoutput>#FindNoCase("International","aaInternationalbb" )#</cfoutput> 
  <cfoutput>#FindNoCase("International","aalbb")#</cfoutput>
```

This will give output as: 3 0 3 0

Comment: Indeed. As a general rule, RajVish, if you come to think that a very commonly-used function "doesn't work", you ought to at least initially conclude *you are wrong about that*, and read the docs, as a first port of call.

Answer (score 1):

findNoCase and Find will expect ( stringtosearch, stringtosearchfrom [,start])

Comment: This should be a comment. This wrong parameter order was already mentioned [in a previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18096426/104223). No need to post the same answer twice.